# TableView error: titleForHeaderInSection/Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift

I am working on a table view project I've seen in a tutorial, then I came across this piece of code that gives me the `**error: Definition conflicts with previous value.**`

The piece of code is:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int, titleForHeaderInSection section:Int)  -> String? {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return animalSelectionTitles[section]

}
```

I have tried to change the String? into String or Int, but String gives me the same error and Int gives me an error on the return line.

Here's my complete code:

```
import UIKit


class AnimalTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var animalsDict = [String: [String]] ()
var animalSelectionTitles = [String] ()

let animals = ["Bear", "Black Swan", "Buffalo", "Camel", "Cockatoo", "Dog", "Donkey", "Emu", "Giraffe", "Greater Rhea", "Hippopotamus", "Horse", "Koala", "Lion", "Llama", "Manatus", "Meerkat", "Panda", "Peacock", "Pig", "Platypus", "Polar Bear", "Rhinoceros", "Seagull", "Tasmania Devil", "Whale", "Whale Shark", "Wombat"]

func createAnimalDict() {
    for animal in animals {
        let animalKey = animal.substringFromIndex(advance(animal.startIndex, 1))
        if var animalValues = animalsDict[animalKey] {
            animalValues.append(animal)
            animalsDict[animalKey] = animalValues
        } else {
            animalsDict[animalKey] = [animal]
        }
    }
    animalSelectionTitles = [String] (animalsDict.keys)
    animalSelectionTitles.sort({ $0 < $1})
    animalSelectionTitles.sort( { (s1:String, s2:String) -> Bool in
        return s1 < s2
    })
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    createAnimalDict()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return animalSelectionTitles.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int, titleForHeaderInSection section:Int)  -> String? {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return animalSelectionTitles[section]

}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel?.text = animals[indexPath.row]

    // Convert the animal name to lower case and 
    // then replace all occurences of a space with an underscore
    let imageFilename = animals[indexPath.row].lowercaseString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "_", options: nil, range: nil)
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: imageFilename)

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

---

1)

You should change your line

```
let animalKey = animal.substringFromIndex(advance(animal.startIndex, 1))
```

Currently it substrings from the 2nd character, which means that for the input `Black Swan` then `animalKey` would be equal to `lack Swan`. Instead you should use the following line:

```
let animalKey = animal.substringToIndex(advance(animal.startIndex, 1))
```

---

2)

There is no method in the `UITableViewDataSource Protocol` which is called `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:titleForHeaderInSection`. Instead you need to split it into the following two methods:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let title = animalSelectionTitles[section]
    return animalsDict[title]!.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return animalSelectionTitles[section]
}
```

---

**UPDATE 1:**

In your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you should also update the retrieving of the animal name to reflect what is stored in the dictionary like so:

```
// Configure the cell...
let secTitle = animalSelectionTitles[indexPath.section]
let animalName = animalsDict[secTitle]![indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel?.text = animalName
```